# Loading page within an allready loaded jquery page!

Tags: jquery

i was wondering whether it is possible to load a second page from a already loaded page using jquery,

i have already done loading the first page, in this case its a gallery i can load all the images i want as thumbs now what i want is to click on em and a pop window that will show image details, i have the script for the pop window too, but when i combine the pop window with the gallery loaded with jquery the pop doesn't work .

```
<a href="detail.php?iid='.$iid.'" class="ajax"><img name="" style="margin:2px;" src="image.php?width=100&height=100&cropratio=2:2&amp;image=/u/'.$file.'"  alt="" /></a>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
    $('a.ajax').click(function() {
        var url = this.href;
        var dialog = $('<div style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
        // load remote content
        dialog.load(
            url, 
            {},
            function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                dialog.dialog();
            }
        );
        //prevent the browser to follow the link
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

as u can see the detail.php gets the imageid through url property, this dose work when i use it the direct gallery.php, the problem only comes when i load gallery.php using jquery though the index.php.

here is the script to load gallery.php using index.php file..

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#gl").click(function()
            {
                //$(this).text("...One Moment Please...");
                $("#container").append('<div id="glr" "></div>')
                .children("#glr").hide()
                .load("gallery.php div#glr", function()
                {
                $("#tet").remove();
                $("#rem").remove();
                $("#glr").slideDown("slow");
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

as u can see in the bellow pic, when i go directly to gallery.php it works.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyf4A.png

this the gallery.php when loaded through index.php with jquery.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqVce.png

i wont the pop detail.php to pop when i load gallery.php ..

any feedbacks will be greatly appreciated,

ThankYou 
M.Amin

Answer (score 0):

Try using .live() jquery api  here's the documentation http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: live dosent work either after i load the gallery page using jquery, directly it works, so basicly still the same thing ..